# how to write antlr4 rule for string

Tags: antlr4

I have the following rules for string and comment:

```
Double_quoted_string : '"' ( ~[\n\r] )* '"'  ;
SL_Comment : '//' .*? '\r'? '\n' -> channel(HIDDEN) ;
```

But I see that for the following input:

```
printf("Hello \"something "); //printf("Bye ");
```

the string token getting generated is:

```
"Hello \"something "); //printf("Bye "
```

i.e. greedily the longest match is taken, without applying the rule for the comment.

I would like the string only to be "Hello \"something ". How should the rules be modified for this?

Comment: Just make it non-greedy: `Double_quoted_string : '"' ( ~[\n\r] )*? '"'  ;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this

```
Double_quoted_string
  : '"' ( ~[\\"\n\r] | '\\' [\\"] )* '"'  
  ;
```

Short explanation of the inner `( ... )*`:

- `~[\\"\n\r]` matches any char except `\`, `"`, `\n` and `\r`
- `'\\' [\\"]` matches `\\` or `\"` *

* if you want to escape more, simply add them to the character class: `'\\' [\\"'tbnrf]` would match `\\`, `\"`, `\'`, `\t`, `\b`, `\n`, `\r` and `\f`

Comment: Thanks for the answer